# Carbon nanotube hydrophobicity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-fields, nanoscience

[Xinyou Ma, Chenghan Li, Alex B. F. Martinson and Gregory A. Voth, Water Assisted Proton Transport in Confined Nanochannels](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.01928)
 states that carbon nanotube is hydrophobic. That means, as I understand it, the water molecule would orient itself with the hydrogen end away from the tube wall. What causes this effect? Is it because there are excess positive charges on the surface of the carbon nanotube surface? If so, what causes this?